# FileReader isn't working?

Tags: javascript, file-io

this is frustrating. I've been running this code in Safari, Firefox and Chrome - all latest versions - and it doesn't work. Is it working for anyone else? I'm getting my file reference from `<input type='file' id='file' name='file'>`

```
console.log("Have now created a new file reader and it looks like this..." + reader);
reader.onload = function() {
var contents = event.target.result;
console.log("File contents: " + contents );
};
reader.onerror = function(event) {
console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
};
reader.readAsText(file);    
}, false);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks,

J.Wells

Comment: In your debugging efforts, have you noticed whether `event` has any value in the event handlers?

Comment: You forgot to *create* the `reader` (or you forgot to post the code); and there are mismatched braces in the end.

Comment: Yes, i didn't post the reader creation code. It's there in the actual code. Here the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trkkazulu/KXStL/24/

Comment: The 'reader' object just doesn't get created.

Comment: @Jair-RohmParkerWells: That code in the fiddle is a completely different one.

Answer (score 3):

> What am i doing wrong?

You seem to have forgotten the `event` parameter of the `onload` handler. Instead of using `event.target`, you also might just use `reader`.

Also, in the fiddle you are creating the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) in a very odd way. You might want to read the introduction [*Using files from web applications* at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).

```
document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0],
        reader = new FileReader();
    console.log("Have now created a new file reader and it looks like this..." + reader);
    reader.onload = function(event) {
//                           ^^^^^
        var contents = event.target.result;
        console.log("File contents: " + contents );
    };
    reader.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);    
}, false);
```

Comment: Nope. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/trkkazulu/KXStL/34/ This code isn't working either. What am i doing wrong here? It's crazy. Everything looks right...

Comment: `if ( !! reader)` checks whether `reader` is truthy - which all objects are, and you always "get nothing". Remove one exclamation mark, or remove the the entire condition since it's useless.